# Save DirectStream RDD into Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, apache-kafka, pymongo

I'm learning MongoDB and, while doing a simple exercise, I have an issue with the store of the data from Kafka consumer to MongoDb by using pymongo_spark.
Indeed of, the saved data into MongoDb are different with those produced by Kafka consumer.

This is Kafka consumer's code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils 
import math
import time
from pyspark import SparkConf
import pymongo_spark
# Important: activate pymongo_spark.
pymongo_spark.activate()

startInformation = {}
oldX = ''
oldY = ''

# Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 3 second
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "OdometryConsumer")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['odometry'], {'metadata.broker.list': 'localhost:9092'})

def getPositionSpeed(line):
fr = open('/Users/en1gma/Desktop/info.txt', 'r')
for l in fr.readlines():
    oldX = float(l.split(' ')[0])
    oldY = float(l.split(' ')[1])
    try:
        oldTs = int(l.split(' ')[2])
    except:
        oldTs = int(time.time())
fr.close()
fields = line[1].split(" ")
robotId = fields[0].split(":")[1]
deltaSpace = float(fields[1].split(":")[1])
thetaTwist = float(fields[2].split(":")[1])
ts = int(fields[3].split(":")[1])
newX = oldX + deltaSpace*(math.cos(thetaTwist))
newY = oldY + deltaSpace*(math.sin(thetaTwist))
try:
    speed = deltaSpace/(ts - oldTs)
except:
    speed = float(0)

fw = open('/Users/en1gma/Desktop/info.txt', 'w')
fw.write(str(newX) + " " + str(newY) + " " + str(ts))
fw.close()

startInformation["robotId"] = str(robotId)
startInformation["x_coordinate"] = str(newX)
startInformation["y_coordinate"] = str(newY)
startInformation["speed"] = str(speed)
startInformation["deltaSpace"] = str(deltaSpace)
startInformation["thetaTwist"] = str(thetaTwist)
startInformation["timeStamp"] = str(ts)

return startInformation

elaborate = kafkaStream.map(getPositionSpeed)

def sendRecord(rdd):
try:
    rdd.saveToMongoDB('mongodb://localhost:27017/db.test')
except:
    pass

elaborate.foreachRDD(sendRecord)

ssc.start()             # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  # Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Can you know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us both the output before concluding that they are different

Comment: The results are different because the data are updated into mongodb every three message. This problem wasn't present before the introduction of mongodb

Comment: In `ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)` you mentioned 3 as batch interval. Did you try changing that?

Comment: I try to change this parameter but nothing isn't changing